# Clang linker transitive dependency

Tags: android, linker, clang, clang++

In gcc there are some flags which enable transitive depencies linking, i.e. if I link my binary with a libA which then links libB, then I can transitively pass the path to the libB, for example.
However I don't see such options for clang, when building for Android, for example, with .bp files.
Dynamic linker won't 'see' the rpath option for libB. Which options are there for clang?

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is rather tricky to set in Android.